# Rails upgrade to 6.1.4.1 causes activerecord argument error wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to activerecord 6.1.4 I'm getting the error message:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 259ms (ActiveRecord: 81.9ms | Allocations: 23397)
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)):
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:33:in `reply_to_conversation_for_chat_view'
{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"=>"*", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"=>"GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, HEAD", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"=>"", "Access-Control-Max-Age"=>"0"}
```

Here are lines 32-33 from conversations_controller#reply_to_conversation_for_chat_view:

```
            receipt =  current_user.reply_to_conversation(@conversation, params[:body], nil, true, true)
            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', msg_time: Time.now, sender: current_user.id, sender_name: current_user.name, body: params[:body]
```

Comment: There's a stack trace after this error, please show it to us. Also: what version are you upgrading from?

Comment: I forget what was my previous version

Comment: Don't you use version control? Please, improve your question so we can help. Stack trace, ruby version and code snippet where the error was raised.

Comment: You should be able to get the previous version from your revision control system (probably git). What does the stack trace look like? What is line 33 of `messages_controller.rb`? Do you have a test suite?

Comment: Also include the code in your controller action.

Comment: I've never used tests Don't know the first thing about them

Comment: I feel like this is a form_tag issue where the params have no parent obect so they're not being passed in a hash (the new convention) but instead as just an array but I think you would still need form_tag for searches and things like that where there's no object or resource

Comment: Line 33 is a call to `ActionCable.server.broadcast`, have you read [its documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionCable/Server/Broadcasting.html#method-i-broadcast)?

Comment: Grzegorz: Good point I'm upgrading from 6.0.0 It's definitely necessary to read the upgade guide on guides.rubyonrails.org The guide says to change gem versions, bundle, and then run ```bin/rails app:update``` from your site's top level directory and then you're on your own with package.json The update task isn't going to change any node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I got everything working My problem was just a bunch of missing modules, version mismatches, stale files, etc What I needed to do was follow the rails upgrade guide The upgrade process includes running `bin/rails app:update` and additionally work through gem updates, module upgrades, etc and had to run `rails g webpacker:install`, `rails g install:react`